# Draw multiple circle instead of histogram in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to create a specific type of histogram in Pine script (v5). I'm trying to draw a circle instead of the columns of a histogram; For example, if the value of the histogram is 4, I want to have 4 circles piled up each other.
Right now I've tried these styles in *plot* drawing:

```py
plot(... , style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3, ... )
plot(... , style = plot.style_columns, linewidth = 3, ... )
plot(... , style = plot.style_histogram, linewidth = 3, ... )
```

The first style gives me a circle, but just 1 circle at the exact value. For more clarification, see the below pictures;

[What I get using style_circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv9JY.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQLi.png)

So is there any trick to draw my custom style?
I have to mention that the drawing has some conditions. As you can see in the pictures, I used transparent color for the plot color based on some conditions.

UPDATE:
I tried to use **label** instead of **plot**, with below method:

```py
circle_text = ""
if prev_sum_index > 0
    for i = 1 to prev_sum_index
        circle_text += "◯\n"

label_color =  greenCond ? color.green : redCond ? color.red : color.rgb(255,255,255,100)
label_yloc = greenCond ? yloc.abovebar: redCond ? yloc.belowbar: yloc.price
label_id = label.new(bar_index - 1, 0, yloc = label_yloc, textcolor = label_color, style=label.style_none, text=circle_text)
```

the `prev_sum_index` is the value of the histogram, which is an integer value. But the `y`location is not quite right; I think the `y` location depends on price, but my indicator's `overlay` is `false` and there is no price!

Comment: Is the max value known?

Comment: @vitruvius , regarding to the calculation and conditions, I can say that it can not have a limited value, such as max or min values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the max number of circles is unknown, your only bet here is using `label`s. The disadvantage is, you will have a limited number of labels on your chart. Therefore, you should add `max_labels_count=500` to your `indicator()` or `strategy()` function.

You mentioned that you are using `overlay=false` so you need to find a base point for your first circle. I just used `0` but you can adapt that according to your needs. The rest of the circles will be on top of the first one adjusted by `\n`.

Here is a function and test code for you:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", max_labels_count=500)

f_draw_circles(n, col) =>
    s = ""

    if (n > 1)
        s := "◯"
        
        for i = 0 to n - 2
            s := s + "\n◯"
    else if (n > 0)
        s := "◯"
    
    label.new(bar_index, 0, s, color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=col)

n = (bar_index % 10)
label_col = (bar_index % 2) == 0 ? color.green : color.red

f_draw_circles(n, label_col)
```

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned on update of my question, the "0" value is not quite right. When I use yloc.belowbar for negative values, the direction of circles are correct, but the position is still somewhere above the base-line which is 0 in my case.